# azcopy (using sas-generator) giving 403 not authorized error

Tags: azure, azcopy

I am using this command to generate SAS,

```
az storage container generate-sas --account-name mystorageaccount --as-user --auth-mode login 
--expiry 2022-02-17T08:19Z --name container1 --permissions dlrw
```

but. when i try to copy my containers using azcopy, it says I  dont have permission.

```
azcopy cp "https://[srcaccount].blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" "https://[destaccount].blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]"
 --recursive
```

Error:

```
RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

   Content-Length: [279]
   Content-Type: [application/xml]
   Date: [Thu, 17 Feb 2022 05:21:16 GMT]
   Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
   X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [xxx-xx-x-x-x-xx]
   X-Ms-Error-Code: [AuthorizationPermissionMismatch]
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [xx-x-x-x-x-xx]
   X-Ms-Version: [2019-12-12]
```

But when I generate SAS for my azure storage account container,  through GUI, I check allowed resources with containers, and then it works.

[SAS GUI Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Fms.png)  How can I allow resources through az client? can someone please help me out with this?

**Edit**:

so I am generating two SAS.
1st one is for : storageaccount => 'storageaccount1' and container => '/Container1'.   (source container in other words, which gives SAS1)

2nd one is for: storageaccount => 'storageaccount1' and container => '/Container2'.    (destination container in other words, which gives SAS2)

and using these two containers in azcopy.

```
azcopy cp "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container1>/<folder2>?<SAS1>" "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container2>/<foldeer2>?<SAS2>" --recursive=true
```

Comment: Another factor is the network configuration of the 2 storage accounts.  The destination storage account will attempt to connect directly to the source storage account.  Are there network access restrictions on either of them?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you are generating a SAS token for a container (i.e. creating a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas)) but using it to copy all blob containers from one account to another which requires an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas).

Please create an Account SAS using [`az storage account generate-sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-generate-sas) and then you should not get the error.

Comment: so I am generating two SAS. 

1st one is for : storageaccount => 'storageaccount1' and container => '/Container1'.   (source container in other words, which gives <SAS1>)

2nd one is for: storageaccount => 'storageaccount1' and container => '/Container2'.    (destination container in other words, which gives <SAS2>)

and using these two containers in azcopy. 



```azcopy cp "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container1>/<folder2>?<SAS1>" "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container2>/<foldeer2>?<SAS2>" --recursive=true```

Comment: I have edited my base question

Comment: I see that you are using Azure AD based login to create the SAS tokens. Can you please check if the user for which the token is acquired to get the SAS token has appropriate permissions (Storage Data Contributor/Owner) on the storage account/container?